# ImportError: cannot import module

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

The package looks like this:

- main.py
- HTTPQuery.py
- SmartDownload.py

in main.py I run `from SmartDownload import DownloadFile`.

in Smartdownload.py I run `from HTTPQuery import Is_ServerSupportHTTPRange`

in HTTPQuery I run `from SmartDownload import DownloadFile`

It seems that I get stuck in a loop, because this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Scripts\mp3grabber\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    import HTTPQuery
  File "C:\Scripts\mp3grabber\HTTPQuery.py", line 6, in <module>
    from SmartDownload import DownloadFile
  File "C:\Scripts\mp3grabber\SmartDownload.py", line 3, in <module>
    from HTTPQuery import Is_ServerSupportHTTPRange
ImportError: cannot import name Is_ServerSupportHTTPRange
```

But I must import second file's functions into the third file and vice-versa.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggest, there is a circular dependency between `HTTPQuery` and `SmartDownload`. The easy fix is to move the import into the functions that require it, e.g.

```
# SmartDownload.py
def download(url):
    from HTTPQuery import Is_ServerSupportHTTPRange
    ...
```

A better solution might be to reorganize your modules. If there is no reasonable way to remove `HTTPQuery`'s dependence on `SmartDownload` or vice versa, consider merging them into one module.

Comment: I didn't know that you could do a singular import to avoid the circular dependency issue.  Cool!

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to re-organize the dependencies so you don't have this circular import problem.  Barring that, you may be able to simply move the line `from SmartDownload import DownloadFile` to the bottom of your HTTPQuery.py file to break the loop.

There's a bit of discussion on circular imports [here](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm).